# How do I show that the integral domain $Z/(p)$ is not an ordered integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

The properties of an ordered integral domain are the following:

**1. Closed under addition in $D^+$**

**2. Closed under multiplication $D^+$**

**3. Satisfy the trichotomy law which either $a=0,a\in D^+, or -a \in D^+$**

I tried creating a multiplication and addition table for $Z/(3)$ and from the results, they're closed under $D^+$. So I figured it has something to do with not satisfying the trichotomy law. I know that $a=0$ is true since I have gotten a sum and product that equals to $0$. Any help please?

Comment: What was the set $D^+$ closed under addition and multiplication that you ended up with? The problem with trichotomy will depend on the choice of $D^+$. Observe that the trichotomy requires *exactly one* of the conditions $a=0$, $a\in D^+$, $-a\in D^+$ to hold for all $a\in\Bbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: trichotomy is actually a bit stronger. It should say exactly one of $a, -a \in D^+$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $1\in D^+$. If you keep adding $1$ to itself $p-1$ times, you arrive at $-1\in D^+$ as well. But by trichotomy, both $1$ and $-1$ cannot be in $D^+$ at the same time.

Comment: How do you get $-1$ if you add $1$ $p-1$ times?

Comment: What is $p$ modulo $p$?

Comment: The last conclusion does not follow directly from trichotomy as stated, but requires the additive closure axiom.

Comment: @Slade Could you elaborate? I thought additive closure was used in my first line only.. In my last line we're simply observing the contradiction. Thanks!

Comment: You get $[0]$ since $p\equiv p(modp)$.

Comment: @HenryLee Good, so what does that make $p-1$?

Comment: @Jake The given trichotomy law is not stated as an exclusive or, though maybe that's a reasonable way to read it (as Jyrki suggests in his comment).  Actually, the way it's stated, $D^+ = D$ is always an ordering.  I suppose that we need some non-degeneracy axiom.  For example, it's enough to assume that $0\notin D^+$.  Then $a,-a\in D^+ \implies 0\in D^+$.

Comment: Oh you get $[-1]$. But I still don't understand what you mean by adding $1$ to $p-1$. Say $p=3$, adding $1$ to itself $2$ times is $1+1$. That would make $2\equiv1(mod1)$.

Comment: @HenryLee $1+1=2\equiv -1 \pmod 3$ and $1+1+1+1\equiv -1 \pmod 5$. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Oh I get it now since $[2]$ also contains $-1$ in $(mod3)$. and $[4]$ contains $-1$ in $(mod5)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ were an ordered integral domain. By the trichotomy law, at least one of $1$ and $2$ must lie in $D^+$. Since $1+2=0$, it follows from closure under addition that $1$ and $2$ cannot both belong to $D^+$.

However, if $1\in D^+$ and $2\not\in D^+$, then $1+1=2\not\in D^+$, contrary to the closure property. Similarly, if $2\in D^+$ and $1\not\in D^+$, then $2+2=1\not\in D^+$, again contradicting the closure property.

Since both cases lead to a contradiction, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be an ordered integral domain. A similar proof should work for general $p$.

Comment: I have trouble formulating a proof with $p$ although I do understand your answer.

Comment: It looks like Jake's answer is essentially what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another argument:
The $p-1$ nonzero elements of $\Bbb Z/(p)$ fall into two subsets of equal size: $D^+$ and $-D^+$, which consists of the negatives of elements of $D^+$. Let $m$ be the largest integer in $[1,p-1]$ whose class is in $D^+$. This is certainly not $p-1$. Then $m+1\in-D^+$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why wouldn't $m$ be $p-1$ and why would $m+1 \in -D^+$?

Comment: $m$ wouldn’t be $p-1$ ’cause the class of $p-1\in-D^+$, on’counta $1\in D^+$. And since the the class of $m$ is in $D^+$ but $m$ is the largest *integer* with this property, the class of $m+1$ will be in $-D^+$.